# How do you use a CAtlStringW with boost format?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost-format

I tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost\format.hpp>
#include <atlstr.h>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ATL::CAtlStringW& string)
{
    return os << string.GetString();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CAtlStringW world = L"world";
    boost::wformat formatter(L"hello %s");
    formatter % world;
    std::wstring formatted = formatter.str();
    return 0;
}
```

and formatted ended up as "hello 004B54D8", but I'd like it to be "hello world".
I've tried some variations like defining the operator<< within namespaces. What am I missing? The operator<< doesn't appear to get called.

Thanks.

boost format documentation provides the following example for formatting a custom types: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/format/example/sample_userType.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Doh.

I missed the 'w's:

```
std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& os, const ATL::CAtlStringW& string)
{
    return os << string.GetString();
}
```